# Water draining below sump pump drain pipe?

Tags: basement, waterproofing, drainage, sump-pump, sump

I live in 6 year old home and I noticed today after rain, that the sewer backflow preventer located in basement floor is full of water!

Basement floor slab is Bone dry but potentially there is water under slab ?

The backflow preventer valve is located couple feet from sump pump pit, I checked sump pit and it seems some water was draining from below the PVC pipe, I wonder maybe if my weeping tiles are installed to high and not collecting water ?

And I seen some sump pits with tiny holes all around I wonder if I should put a hole to try to collect the water from under the floor.

Comment: Does your sump pump discharge into the sewer?

Comment: Full sewer, backflow preventer doing its job? Just to consider the obvious, with various places flooding right now.

Comment: Yes there's water under the slab. The ground is wet, especially with "rain today". That's how it works. Since your basement floor is bone dry, it seems that the house is working properly, what's your question/concern?